# UsePythonVersion@0 sets wrong Python versions in Azure Pipelines

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I added Python 3.9 to self hosted Agent toolcache successfully as shown in docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-python-version-v0?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)

I am running the following pipeline:

```
trigger: none

pool: 
  name: self-hosted-agent
  demands:
    - Agent.Name -equals agentname
    - agent.name -equals agentname
    - Agent.OS -equals Linux
steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.9' 
    addToPath: true 
- script: |
    python --version
    python3 --version
    python print('Hello!')

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Run Python Code
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      python --version
      python print('Hello!')
```

I can see in the logs that `UsePythonVersion@0` can find this additionally installed python 3.9.1 version:

```
Starting: UsePythonVersion
==============================================================================
Task         : Use Python version
Description  : Use the specified version of Python from the tool cache, optionally adding it to the PATH
Version      : 0.214.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version
==============================================================================
Found tool in cache: Python 3.9.1 x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /home/.../myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.9.1/x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /home/.../myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.9.1/x64/bin
Finishing: UsePythonVersion
```

But when I check python version in script:

```
Starting: CmdLine
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.212.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/.../myagent/_work/_temp/0225cb7f-9153-4b7c-ad42-321b8b9bfa97.sh
Python 2.7.16
Python 3.7.3
```

I get wrong versions (probably the ones that are installed globally in the Agent Pool machine)
But as I understand `UsePythonVersion@0` task should change the version of python to the one defined in the task?

Comment: try `python39 --version` or `python39 ('Hello!')`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk when I run python39 --version I get:  `/home/.../myagent/_work/_temp/fb5b1d47-a123-415b-a071-7fc6cd0a9bb2.sh: line 3: python39: command not found`

Comment: My bad, try `python3.9`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk but shouldnt the task provided by MSFT set the `python` command that executes the python code in pipeline to be correct version, instead of using specific version of python?

Comment: idk... did you try the `python3.9`?